# Regular Expression, with number spaces dashes limited to 8-13 numbers

Tags: regex

I am trying to do a regular expression to validate a number between 9 and 13 numbers, but the  sequence can have dashes and spaces and the ideal is to not have more than one space or dash consecutively.

this rule allow me to control the validation between 9 and 13

```
/^[\d]{9,13}$/
```

now to add dashes and spaces

```
/^[\d -]{9,13}$/
```

I think I need something like that, but I need to count the numbers

```
/^[ -](?:\d){9,13}$/
```

Any tips?

Comment: Would it be OK to have more than one expression to do everything, or is there a reason to do it "all at once"? Sometimes clarity trumps cleverness... actually, most of the time.

Comment: Regex alone are probably not the right tool for this. Checking for two consecutive spaces or dashes would be easier with a normal string function that looks for the occurrence of those two specific strings.

Comment: Are these spaces/dashes significant in any way or just customary (like in phone number) and could be disregarded sou you'd just store the digits without formatting?

Comment: The title says 8-13 numbers, yet the question implies 9-13 numbers. Which you want? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you don't want leading or trailing spaces and dashes. This should do it.

```
/^\d([- ]*\d){8,12}$/
```

Regular expression:

```
\d          digits (0-9)
 (          group and capture to \1 (between 8 and 12 times)
 [- ]*      any character of: '-', ' ' (0 or more times)
   \d       digits (0-9)
 ){8,12}    end of \1
```

Another option: A digit followed any number of space or dash 8-12 times, followed by a digit.

```
/^(\d[- ]*){8,12}\d$/
```

Answer (score 4):

Notice how my regex starts and ends with a digit.  Also, this prevents consecutive spaces and dashes.

`/^\d([ \-]?\d){7,12}$/`

Comment: Probably should be `{8,12}`.

Comment: I originally had that, but noticed the title specified otherwise. See my question/comment above.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming a dash following a space or vice versa is ok:**

```
^( -?|- ?)?(\d( -?|- ?)?){9,13}$
```

**Explanation:**

`( -?|- ?)` - this is equivalent to `( | -|-|- )`. Note that there can't be 2 consecutive dashes or spaces here, and this can only appear at the start or directly after a digit, so this prevents 2 consecutive dashes or spaces in the string.

And there clearly must be exactly one digit in `(\d( -?|- ?)?)`, thus the `{9,13}` enforces 9-13 digits.

**Assuming a dash following a space or vice versa is NOT ok:**

```
^[ -]?(\d[ -]?){9,13}$
```

Explanation similar to the above.

Both of the above allows the string to start or end with a digit, dash or space.

Answer (score 0):

Use look aheads to assert the various constraints:

```
/^(?!.*(  |--))(?=(\D*\d){9,13}\D*$)[\d -]+$/
```